# Alignment and Table Issues when Copy-Pasting from Doc to Summernote Editor

Tags: html, django, summernote

I am experiencing alignment and table-related issues when copying and pasting content from a document into the Summernote editor. The issues persist when displaying the data on the website. I believe this is a significant problem that needs attention.

Steps to Reproduce:

Copy content from a document.
Paste the content into the Summernote editor.
Observe alignment and table issues.

Expected Behavior:
I expect the copied content to be displayed correctly in terms of alignment and table formatting on the website.

Actual Behavior:
While copy and paste from doc it is showing alignment and lot of issues in website.